# Add component props on the fly when component renders in react native

Tags: react-native

I have an array of components

```
let components = [
    {name: 'Home', component: <Home />},
    {name: 'About', component: <About />},
    {name: 'Contact', component: <Contact />},
];
```

Initially all the components have no props. Is there a way I can add props on the fly when the component render?

```
components.map((c, i) => (
    <View key={i}>
      {c.component} // e.g <Home params={{data: []}} />
    </View>
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

Create a Higher order component who's only task will be to copy props from its own props to child component.

```
<WrapperCOmponent {...props}> // pass props you want to pass dynamically
{c.component}
</WrapperCOmponent>
```

HOC logic:

```
const hoc = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {


return (
<div>
  <WrappedComponent {...props}>
    {props.children.toUpperCase()}
  </WrappedComponent>
</div>)}
```